# How to make a for loop with multiple if conditions

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a df (shape (5928, 22)) and I'm trying to create a new column and add values based on multiple conditions.

The conditions would be:

```
    if CH == 20 then value = 268,34
    if CH == 24 then value = 322,02
    if CH == 30 then value = 492,65
    if CH == 40 then value = 536,69

    and

    if CH == 20 & ID in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304) then value = 417,43
    if CH == 24 & ID in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304) then value = 500,91
    if CH == 30 & ID in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304) then value = 626,34
    if CH == 40 & ID in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304) then value = 834,85
```

When I try to add a new column and append the values based on the first block of conditions it works perfectly.

```
new_value = []

for row in df['CH']:
    if row == 20:
        new_value.append(268.34)
    elif row == 24:
        new_value.append(322.02)
    elif row == 30:
        new_value.append(402.65)
    elif row == 40:
        new_value.append(536.69)
    else:
        new_value.append(0)

df['new_value'] = new_value
```

When I tried to add other conditions it wont work. Code would be something like:

```
new_value = []

for row in df['CH']:
    if row == 20 and df['ID'] not in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304):
         new_value.append(268.34)
    elif row == 20 and df['ID'] in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304):
        new_value.append(417.43)
    elif row == 24 and df['ID'] not in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304):
        new_value.append(268.34)
    elif row == 24 and df['ID'] in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304):
        new_value.append(500.91)
    elif row == 30 and df['ID'] not in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304):
        new_value.append(268.34)
    elif row == 30 and df['ID'] in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304):
        new_value.append(626.34)
    elif row == 40 and df['ID'] not in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304):
        new_value.append(268.34)
    elif row == 40 and df['ID'] in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304):
        new_value.append(834.85)
    else:
        new_value.append(0)

    df['new_value'] = new_value
```

When I try the code above I get the following error message:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I don't know how to go from here. In SQL I would use two simple WHERE statements but I cannot get it to work in Python.

Comment: For future reference `dict` and `set` may be useful to look into. I could answer this question using those but I believe there is a better pandas solution so I let one of those wizards deal with it.

Comment: Please do a print statement of : print(row == 20) inside your loop. We need to see whether this is a boolean. It might be doing pointwise check and thus is a series...

Comment: You have a bug combining a row check (row==40) returning a bool with a coloumn check returning a series( df['ID'] not in ((5105561300, 5105561301)).

Comment: Try something more link (df.CH==20)&(df.ID.isin(5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304)==False), to vectorize

Comment: Great observation, Peter! When I tried your suggestion I got  # TypeError: isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option #1: Two `map`, one `isin`, and an `np.where`

```
mtrue  = {20: 268.34, 24: 322.02, 30: 492.65, 40: 536.69}
mfalse = {20: 417.43, 24: 500.91, 30: 626.34, 40: 834.85}
ids = {5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304}

df['new_value'] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(ids), df['CH'].map(mtrue), df['CH'].map(mfalse))
```

---

#### Option #2: One `map` and a `zip`

```
mtrue  = {20: 268.34, 24: 322.02, 30: 492.65, 40: 536.69}
mfalse = {20: 417.43, 24: 500.91, 30: 626.34, 40: 834.85}
ids = {5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304}
m = {
    (b, k): v for b, d in zip([True, False], [mtrue, mfalse])
    for k, v in d.items()
}

df['new_value'] = [*map(m.get, zip(df['ID'].isin(ids), df['CH']))]
```

#### Equivalent to:

Just in case you can do `[*map...]`

```
df['new_value'] = [m[t] for t in zip(df['ID'].isin(ids), df['CH']))]
```

Comment: Brilliant!! It worked! the only thing I had to change was switch mtrue to mfalse..

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is in `df['ID']`, change how you loop through the rows to the following should fix the ERROR message:

```
for row, id in zip(df['CH'], df['ID']):
    if row == 20 and id not in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304):
        new_value.append(268.34)
    elif row == 20 and id in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304):
        ...
```

Since your dataset is not very big, you can use a list comprehension to handle this task:

```
# a set of ids to check existence
wlist = { 5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304 }

# the value of each key is a list with the first element using the value 
# when id not in wlist and the 2nd element the value when id is in wlist
mapping = {
    20: [268.34, 417.43]
  , 24: [322.02, 500.91]
  , 30: [492.65, 626.34]
  , 40: [536.69, 834.85]
}

# new_value will depend on if CH is in mapping and id in wlist
df['new_value'] = [ mapping[ch][int(id in wlist)] if ch in mapping else 0 for ch, id in zip(df.CH, df.ID) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could consolidate this quite a bit, and avoid redundancy:

```
default = 268.34

for row in df['CH']:
    id_check = df['ID'] in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304)
    if row == 20:
        new_value = 417.43
    elif row == 24:
        new_value = 500.91
    elif row == 30:
        new_value = 626.34
    elif row == 40
        new_value = 834.85
    else:
        new_value = 0
    df['new_value'] = default if not id_check else value
```

Or, you could map it:

```
def get_new_value(row):
    d = { 20: 417.43,
             24: 500.91,
             30: 626.34,
             40: 834.85 }
    return d.get(row, 0)

default = 268.34
for row in df['CH']:
    id_check = df['ID'] in (5105561300, 5105561301, 5105561302, 5105561304)
    new_value = default if not id_check else get_new_value(row)

    df['new_value'] = new_value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

There is no default value. The value changes based on two conditions (CH and ID). Maybe I didnt understand your suggestion

Comment: @cebs in the last snippet of your OP code, you're assigning the same value of 268.34 whenever the `df['ID']` is **not** in that tuple of values. call it whatever you want, but it looks like a "default" to me, so that's why I named it as such. Maybe that was a typo, because in your other code you're using some different values. You might want to revise your question so that it's less ambiguous.

Comment: jxc's solution below is similar, but accoutns for the varying values you used in your earlier code.